# Vertex buffer object won't render, other primitives will

Tags: opengl, assimp

I'm loading some scenes/objects from files using assimp, and I had them displaying properly earlier — but rewrote my MVP matrix setup (which had been terribly written and was incomprehensible).

Now, most primitives which I draw in the standard rendering pipeline seem to be appearing just fine. I have a wireframe cube around the origin and can also put in a triangle. But no matter what I do, my ASSIMP-loaded object refuses to be rendered, as a wireframe or as a solid.

I suspect the mistake I'm making is terribly obvious. **[I've tried to reduce the code to a minimal example.](https://github.com/mohawkjohn/lidargl/tree/argh)**

The object should look like a rock and it should show up within the wireframe box.

Since I haven't much altered the mesh code, I'm guessing the problem is in `scene.h` or `main.cpp`.

The old version had GLSL programs, but I eliminated all mention of those here. My understanding from the OpenGL Superbible is that shaders aren't required, though. So that can't be it, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The old version had GLSL programs, but I eliminated all mention of those here.  My understanding from the OpenGL Superbible is that shaders aren't required, though.

They are if you want to use generic vertex attributes via `glVertexAttribPointer()`.  Without a shader OpenGL has no way of knowing attribute `0` is a vertex or `1` contains a texture coordinate.

Use [`glVertexPointer()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glVertexPointer.xml) and friends if you don't want to use shaders.

Comment: Can `glVertexPointer()` still be used to store normals even if I'm not prepared to use them yet? Or do I pretty much have to use shaders the way I have my data laid out?

Comment: No, `glVertexPointer()` is for vertex positions, not normals. [`glNormalPointer()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glNormalPointer.xml) is for normals.  If you don't enable the `GL_NORMAL_ARRAY` [client state](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glEnableClientState.xml) OpenGL won't try to read any normals.